# Where are the volume mixer startup options? Is there in regedit?

Tags: windows-10, volume-mixer

I want to know where the initial volume of the windows mixer is located.

Answer (score 4):

> I want to know where the initial volume of the windows mixer is located.

Okay, so your question wasn't clear to me initially so I probably provided way too much detail below but I'll leave that as ***bonus material*** I suppose in case you find that helpful.

To control the default volume level of the **Windows 10 Volume Mixer** I've provided a method below that doesn't require registry hacks and I confirmed works just fine.

Basically you'll [download the tool](http://nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html), copy it to a folder as explained in the below referenced material, and then create a simple batch script with the logic in it as I put in the below **Batch Script Example**.  You'll then create a Windows Task Scheduler task to run it to adjust the volume per the setting you specify at logon, startup, and so on. Each time the task is triggered the volume will adjust accordingly.

**Batch Script Example**

*Note that the value of 0 means the lowest volume setting as described below and the path is the path as described below as well. You'll need to make adjustments to these parts for your particular needs.*

```
@ECHO OFF
"C:\Program Files\Nircmd\nircmd.exe" setsysvolume 0
EXIT /B
```

**Task Scheduler**

- You can probably place the batch file in the startup folder and see
  if that'll suit you need; otherwise, you can use Windows Task
  Scheduler and schedule the batch file and put a trigger on it for
  executing it **On connection to user session** and **At log on**.
- [image: List item]
- [image]

> [Nircmd - Download and Volume Settings](http://edmullen.net/audio_w7.php)
>
> Using this utility we can achieve the goals of both volume control
>   setting and muting. [Download the utility at Nir's Web
>   site.](http://nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html) It is a ZIP file. I
>   simply created a folder in my Program Files folder called SetVol and
>   unzipped the contents into it.
>
> `"G:\Program Files\SetVol\nircmd.exe" setsysvolume 0`
>
> substituting the correct drive letter for your system. This example
>   sets the system volume to zero.
>
> This table shows some common volume level percentages and the value to
>   use for the nircmd shortcut. It is based on a maximum volume level
>   value of 65,635 units.
>
> [image]
>
> <sub>[source](http://edmullen.net/audio_w7.php)</sub>

---

### BONUS MATERIAL

> **Where are the volume mixer startup options? Is there in regedit?**

In addition to the ***Windows 10*** **Volume Mixer** being in this location: `C:\Windows\System32\SndVol.exe` (or `%windir%\System32\SndVol.exe`),

- [image]

you can follow the below instructions referenced on the steps to follow to edit the registry for enabling the older GUI of ***Windows Volume Mixer***.

---

> ### [How to enable the old Volume control in Windows 10](http://winaero.com/blog/enable-old-volume-control-in-windows-10/)
>
> To restore the old volume applet in Windows 10, follow these steps:
>
> 1. Open [Registry Editor](http://winaero.com/blog/windows-registry-editor-for-dummies/).
> 2. Go to the following Registry key:
>
> `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows
>   NT\CurrentVersion\MTCUVC`
>
> Tip: See [how to jump to the desired Registry key with one
>   click](http://winaero.com/blog/how-to-jump-to-the-desired-registry-key-with-one-click/).
>
> Create the MTCUVC subkey if you do not have it.
>
> 3. Create a new 32-bit DWORD value named EnableMtcUvc and leave its value as 0.
>
> [image]
>
> 4. Sign out and log in back to your Windows account. Alternatively, you can just restart the Explorer shell. Actually, for many users this
>      tweak works instantly, so try to click the speaker systray icon first.
>
> Before:
>
> [image]
>
> After:
>
> [image]
>
> <sub>[source](http://winaero.com/blog/enable-old-volume-control-in-windows-10/)</sub>

Comment: Which bit of your answer addresses "where is stored the inital volume of the windows mixer"?

Comment: @DavidPostill Fixed, not sure how I interpreted that based on my initial answer but I fixed it with a workable solution which I confirmed works 100% as expected on Windows 10.

Comment: Nice answer +1 ;)

Comment: Thanks. But I searching for a standard way to change the initial options.

Comment: I could evaluate the use of an external application. But the tool sugested by @PIMP_JUICE_IT is not open source (I can not see what it does).

Comment: @EmilioPlatzer This is *freeware** and the **License** detail is at the bottom of the links from my answer... the direct link to the 64-bit is here: http://nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd-x64.zip and the 32-bit tool is here: http://nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.zip. These are tools which do NOT require installation too -- just download the ZIP file and then extract the exe to a folder and create the batch script. None of this should require you purchasing anything and again it's FREEWARE.

Comment: @EmilioPlatzer Were you able to look over my answer and did you get a chance to read my above comment regarding this being FREEWARE? I'm not familiar with another way to do this so this should be a simple solution that does NOT require purchasing anything and it doesn't request installing anything either so I wanted to be sure you understand this is a free solution other than what time you'd spend getting and extracting the file and creating the simple batch file and creating the Task Scheduler task. Please send me an update when you get a moment and let me know your thoughts.

Comment: Hi @PIMP_JUICE_IT. I am very grateful to you for your reply. I don't care about paying. Freeware is not the same to open source or to free software. I prefer a solution that shows where is the config stored or an application with de source code. I'll keep looking for an answer to my question. Installing a "no warranty, nor source code app" is not in my options.

Comment: Hi @PIMP_JUICE_IT - great answer! Do you perhaps also know how to set the default audio DEVICE? See http://superuser.com/questions/1109657/set-new-audio-device-default-for-volume-mixer-in-windows-10 - Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

The audio settings per application can be found in the registry at: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\LowRegistry\Audio\PolicyConfig\PropertyStore`

**[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ma09.png)**

The values stored there are in hexadecimal format.