# Set new audio device default for volume mixer in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, audio, volume-mixer

I use two audio devices:

- Default (audio) device "Realtec Digital Output (Optical)"
- Default communication device "Lautsprecher (Speaker)"

---

**My goal:**
I want to have the default audio volume on my default communication device, instead of the default device - at all times.

**What I tried so far:**
Changing the volume mixer to my communication device explicitly works temporary, but as soon as I close the settings window, the default audio volume is reset again to the default audio device.

Step 1: Clicking on volume shows me the default device:

[image]

Step 2: Changing the volume mixer to my communication device manually:

[image]

[image]

Step 3: Clicking again on volume does not keep the change :(

[image]

---

### **How can I make it permanent that windows uses my communication device for default volume control?**

Comment: See if this answer helps you with your need, if so then this is a duplicate question perhaps: http://superuser.com/questions/1106305/where-are-the-volume-mixer-startup-options-is-there-in-regedit/1106316#1106316

Comment: @PIMP_JUICE_IT Thank you, it's close, but I don't need to initially set the volume, I want to be able to always change the volume with my keyboard of my communication device (instead of my standard device)